# Reset folder ownership on damaged external HD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, permissions

I have my old laptop hard drive, and I need to get some files from it. Problem is, they're in the user folder, which is not accessible normally, and I need to take ownership of them first. The only way to do that seems to be taking ownership of the entire directory (recursively), which runs for a few minutes and then fails, most likely because the drive is damaged, and I still can't access anything.

Is there any tool that gives me low level access to the HD without having to deal with permission shenanigans? It seems odd that I can hold the drive in my hands but can't access the data on it. Preferably something I can run on windows, because I know I could do that from Linux but I don't have it installed here.

Comment: You can mount the drive under OSX or Linux and they will ignore windows permissions.

Comment: That's what I meant, I'd need to install Linux first. There's no way to do that on Windows, then?

Answer (score 1):

You can load a Linux distribution (for example knoppix) on a cd or usb 
stick. Than you need to change boot-priority in Bios/Uefi so that the pc boots it.
After that you can mount the HDD and acces the files you need.